# One preparedstatement for multiple tables Java

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

1) Can I use one prepared statement to pass data to multiple tables from java? where I am using JDBC driver.

```
try
        {
            conn = ac.getConnection();
            String insert = "INSERT INTO PPN_WORKFLOW(C2_F_Date,C2_Completed) VALUES(?,?)";
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
            stmt.setDate(1, date);//question 2
            stmt.setInt(2, 1);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            stmt.close();
            String insert2 = "INSERT INTO CREATE_ERF(Purc_Part_New_F_Date,Purc_Part_New_Completed) "
                    + "VALUES(?,?)";
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert2);
            stmt.setDate(1, date);
            stmt.setInt(2,1);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        finally
        {
            if(stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }

            if(conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        }
```

Here I am using stmt(PreparedStatement) for table PPN_WORKFLOW and CREATE_ERF?

2) the PPN_WORKFLOW table consists of more paremeters like

```
PPN_WORKFLOW(C1_S_Date,C2_F_Date,C2_Completed)
```

but I would like to update 2 and 3 parameter, So Is my code is correct.

Comment: It is not clear to me what your actual question is. You are also **NOT** using one `PreparedStatement` object, you are using two and forgetting to close the first one.

Comment: I mean, can i use one prepared statement to pass the values to 2 tables?

Comment: If you are asking if a single `PreparedStatement` can execute two different queries: no it can't. Otherwise please try to rephrase your question and be more specific.

Comment: I am confused as to why you are asking, as your code is also using two different `PreparedStatement` objects...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO PPN_WORKFLOW(C2_F_Date,C2_Completed) VALUES(?,?)";
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
```

Look at `prepareStatement()` like a factory method. It returns an object, in a certain state, given the input. The input you pass to it, at this point, is the `INSERT` statement.

Attempting to reuse the same object for a different purpose doesn't make sense, because the method has returned an object tailored for the argument you provided, in `insert`. You would need to create another object, tailored to that different purpose. Which is what you do in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Insert values to each table at a time if the second depends on the first using `try`... `while`....

```
try{
        //insert to first table
        ///while true
    try{

     //insert to second table
        }finally{


        }
        }finally{
    //close resources
    }
```