# postgresql update multiple tables in single query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, common-table-expression

I have 2 tables as below:

1. serial_table

   ```
   id CHARACTER VARYING(20),
   serial_key CHARACTER VARYING(20),
   PRIMARY KEY(id, serial_key)
   ```
2. serial_rate:

   ```
   id CHARACTER VARYING(20), 
   serial_key CHARACTER VARYING(20),
   rate NUMERIC,
   PRIMARY KEY(id, serial_key),
   FOREIGN KEY (id, serial_key) REFERENCES serial_table(id, serial_key)
   ```

now I want to update `serial_rate.rate` and `serial_table.serial_key` from a single SQL Query like :

```
UPDATE inventory.serial_table AS s 
JOIN inventory.serial_rate AS r 
ON (s.id, s.serial_key) = (r.id, r.serial_key) 
SET s.serial_key = '0002', r.rate = 22.53
WHERE (s.id, s.serial_key) = ('01', '002');
```

Which I know is incorrect. **Is there a possible way to do this** as I would like to use the statement to create a `PreparedStatement` in Java?

**EDIT**
This question is not about `PreparedStatements` in Java It is about SQL Syntax that I wish to pass as parameter while creating a `PreparedStatement`. **I don't want any answer about `PreparedStatement`**.

Comment: Do you really intend to update `serial_table.serial_key` ,  a PK component? And: should `serial_rate.serial_key` also be updated (also a PK component, and FK to the first) ? If not: the FK constraint could be violated.

Comment: @wildplasser the first answer is yes and as for the second part the FK is ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT.

Comment: possible duplicate of [One preparedstatement for multiple tables Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276124/one-preparedstatement-for-multiple-tables-java)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I am unable to understand why you think that this question is similar to the one you have linked? I am not getting the answer to what i want in that link.

Comment: I would remove all the mentions of "prepared statement" if your question is only about SQL syntax.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a CTE thing (but I don't know how to wrap it into a prepared Java-thing)

```
WITH src AS (
        UPDATE serial_rate
        SET rate = 22.53, serial_key = '0002'
        WHERE serial_key = '002' AND id = '01'
        RETURNING *
        )
UPDATE serial_table dst
SET serial_key = src.serial_key
FROM src
-- WHERE dst.id = src.id AND dst.serial_key  = '002'
WHERE dst.id = '01' AND dst.serial_key  = '002'
        ;
```

Comment: This is still two statements, it's not as immediately clear are just doing two update statements in a transaction/sproc, and will be more difficult to implement as a prepared statement (think a long ugly string with variables all over the place)

Comment: No, they are chained together (rather clumsily). Hint: there is only one semicolon. Just put `EXPLAIN` in front of it, and you'll see that it will result in one query plan for the combined updates.

Comment: It's effectively a subquery though right?  It's two queries with one query plan?

Comment: @DanField: No, it's just one single query. And of course it has only one query plan.The trick is the combination of a CTE and the usage of RETURNING in the first UPDATE-command, that will be used in the second UPDATE-command.

Comment: @wildplasser is there any way that we can use the `serial_key` and `id` in the above query just once?

Comment: @Blip: yes that's possible with another CTE in the query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/75387/1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name why don't you post this as a new answer to my question?

Comment: I had no idea this was possible - this is such a great technique, as it helped me update rows with the minimum number of both dead tuples *and* issued statements.

Comment: Beware of CTEs, though. Before Postgres 11//12 (?) CTEs wer always executed once, in isolation. For larger CTE's this can effectively ruin your query. (since CTEs have no structure, the only way to acces them is by means of a heap scan, which is often sub-optimal)

Answer (score 5):

This was what was posted by **a_horse_with_no_name** on sqlfiddle.com:

```
   WITH id_values (new_key, old_key, id) as (
      values ('0002', '002', '01')
    ), src AS (
      UPDATE serial_rate
          SET rate = 22.53, 
              serial_key = (select new_key from id_values)
      WHERE serial_key = (select old_key from id_values)
        AND id = (select id from id_values)
      RETURNING *
    )
    UPDATE serial_table dst
       SET serial_key = src.serial_key
    FROM src
    WHERE dst.id = (select id from id_values)
      AND dst.serial_key = (select old_key from id_values)
    ;
```

This is actually a modified version of what was posted by **wildplasser** as a  reply to my query that whether the `serial_key` field could be used once.