# Room Database query for multiple tables in one statement

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

How can I provide one statement for multiple tables in Dao for Room Database in Kotlin?
I have such code:

```
@Query("UPDATE cis06zebraz, cis06zebrap 
SET cis06zebraz.stav = 1,cis06zebrap.stav=1 
WHERE cis06zebraz.doklad=cis06zebrap.doklad 
AND cis06zebraz.exp = cis06zebrap.exp 
AND cis06zebraz.stav = 0 
AND cis06zebraz.zebra = :zebra")
fun updDatabase(zebra:String)
```

but there is an error on comma after first table. I tried Transaction or @UPDATE in Dao but nothing is working.

Comment: I don't think you can simply update 2 tables from one UPDATE call...  You'd need to do something fancy like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898244/postgresql-update-multiple-tables-in-single-query

Comment: @tim_yates Thanks, I thought so. Problem is that e.g. in Sybase database it is working.

Comment: "Why in this dbms works and in another one it doesn't work? " That's a wrong thinking, You can compare them but don't expect the same thing to work in every dbms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite's [UPDATE](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html) only allows a single table to be updated as per :-

[image]

You either need to have multiple updates run (possibly combined and driven through a single function) OR you could utilise a [TRIGGER](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) that will update the second table when the first is updated. Noting that Room doesn't support the generation of Triggers via annotations so you would have to introduce these via a callback (`onCreate` or `onOpen`).

Here's an example of a TRIGGER :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cis06zebraz;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cis06zebrap;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cis06zebraz (stav,doklad,exp,zebra);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cis06zebrap (stav,doklad,exp);
/*<<<<< THE TRIGGER >>>>>*/
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS cis06zebrap_update_after_cis06zebraz_update 
    AFTER UPDATE OF stav ON cis06zebraz
    BEGIN
        /* NOTE that new. represents values from the updated table */
        UPDATE cis06zebrap SET stav = 1 WHERE cis06zebrap.doklad = new.doklad AND cis06zebrap.exp = new.exp;
    END
;
/* Add some testing data  3 rows into Z table*/
INSERT INTO cis06zebraz VALUES (0,1,'x','zebra');
INSERT INTO cis06zebrap VALUES (0,1,'y');
INSERT INTO cis06zebrap VALUES (0,1,'x');
/* 2 rows into P table */
INSERT INTO cis06zebraz VALUES (0,2,'x','zebra');
INSERT INTO cis06zebrap VALUES (0,2,'y');
/* Display the original data */
SELECT 'Z' AS i,* FROM cis06zebraz UNION SELECT 'P',*,'n/a' FROM cis06zebrap ORDER BY doklad,i DESC;
/* Do the Update */
UPDATE cis06zebraz SET stav = 1 WHERE doklad = 1;
/* Display the  data after the update */
SELECT 'Z' AS i,* FROM cis06zebraz UNION SELECT 'P',*,'n/a' FROM cis06zebrap ORDER BY doklad,i DESC;
/* Cleanup the testing environment */
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS cis06zebrap_update_after_cis06zebraz_update; /*(no need as trigger should be dropped when table is)*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cis06zebraz;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cis06zebrap;
```

The first query before the update shows:-

[image]

i.e. all rows have 0 in the stav column.

After the update then :-

[image]

As can be seen the Z row for doklad 1 (highlighted) has been updated and one of the P rows has been updated according for doklad 1 (highlighted). However, the P row for doklad 1 that is exp y has not been updated by the trigger (as new.exp equates to x)